# iPhone XML data to be encrypted

Tags: php, iphone, security, encryption

Our application gets all the data from PHP/Mysql server in XML format

but now client don't want data to be appeared as it is,
he fears, anyone who knows those .php file links can access all data on server and will become a competitor to him.

so i want to know is there any encryption available which i can use in php and decryption in ios.

or SSL is the only option?

EDIT: our php file returns XML data and client is bothered that competitors can get data,
so i want to send encrypted data into XML and decrypt it in iPhone, so is there any good solution for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL is the most straightforward option, but you should probably also add a challenge/response so that every request is accompanied by a one time hash.  This means that only devices that can create a valid 'key' can access the data, as opposed to anyone who can see the URL endpoint.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that please?

Comment: SSL requires installing a cert and running over HTTPS - this ensures that traffic is encrypted. A simple authentication would be for the device and application to share a secret string as a key. Then in a request you could pass a challenge and token together. The challenge could be a clear text random string, and the token a one way hash (eg. md5) of secret shared string + the clear text challenge. The server can then verify the hash and be sure that the device has generated it properly. This would offer a lightweight and fairly robust auth provided the source is safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some kind of authorization mechanism (something like oauth or a more basic one) so only authorized applications can get the XML data from server.